# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).magnificPopup is not a function - Wordpress - Theme

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm using a WordPress 4.6.1 with Impreza 3.8.1 theme. Also I have installed Visual Composer plugin.

My problems looks like this:
[print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zrzM.jpg)

What to do?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks all, guys!

Actualy, i've found this, but the theme needs an update.

"Go to Theme Options > Advanced Settings, and turn off ‘Dynamically load theme JS components"

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed Magnific Popup or included it correct?

Take a look at http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html

Comment: Excuse me, but I don't get it. I'm not using this. I just know about Wordpress plugins and themes..

Comment: The Impreza theme is using Magnific Popup for their image popups, and your error says that the function is not found, are you using the latest version of Impreza?

Comment: If you go to https://themeforest.net/item/impreza-retina-responsive-wordpress-theme/6434280/comments you can see that other persons using the Impreza theme have the same problem as you do, there are solutions to this among the comments.

Comment: Yes. 3.8.1 ... Please, explain me exactly the steps. Thank you.

Comment: After update the theme to version 3.8.1 ( or earlier ) the javascript-library “jquery.magnific-popup.js” is not included in the frontend. I fixed this by editing the “functions.php” in the child-theme:

function `fuege_javascripts_ein() { } add_action( ‘wp_enqueue_scripts’, ‘fuege_javascripts_ein’ );`

`wp_enqueue_script(
    'jqueryMagnificPopup',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/framework/js/jquery.magnific-popup.js',
    array( 'jquery' )
);`

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that `values` is being combined with `item.data`:

```
if(item.data) {
    values = $.extend(item.data, values);
}
```

When item.data has array integer keys, then `key.split` attempts to operate an on integer, which of course breaks.

Looking down the stack, it seems to happen if you keep a reference to the options object passed to `magnificPopup` or `instance.addGroup` and call one of those functions multiple times. Somewhere that reference to the options object is being mutated by magnific popup.

A user can fix this on their end by cloning the options object when passing it to magnific popup, but it should probably be fixed some way in the plugin itself (either by checking for integer keys, not mutating the options object, or preferably both).

Answer (score 0):

Magnific popup needs three files, but WordPress already have jQuery, so you need to include two files.

Check that both files are linked correctly.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css">

<script src="magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
```